# Setting Label background style with getStyle in libgdx

Tags: colors, background, styles, label, libgdx

I want to change the background style of just one label, which is in its own table, and in it's own layer which is added on top of others in a stack. However, when I assign it, ALL Labels, in all other layers of other tables also get assigned that background. I don't understand why that would happen. I am using libgdx 0.9.8. The skinLibgdx I create is using a basic png with fonts and small background images (that's where the "white" comes from).

```
lblGameMessage = new Label(" ", skinLibgdx.get(LabelStyle.class));  //skinLibgdx is a Skin - TextureAtlas
...
lblGameMessage.getStyle().background = skinLibgdx.newDrawable("white", 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
```

Is this a bug? Why would all other labels be affected by this?
After that line, I try to set the other labels back to black color, but then my lblGameMessage also gets set to black.

```
lblLevel = new Label("Level: ", skinLibgdx.get(LabelStyle.class));
...
lblLevel.getStyle().background = skinLibgdx.newDrawable("white", 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Which constructor are you using for the `lblGameMessage` and `lblLevel` objects?  Its quite possible they are sharing a style instance.

Comment: Edited the question with constructor. I never create a LabelStyle, didn't quite understand the documentation & reason for needing one. More comments to the given answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you created a new LabelStyle:

```
LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle();
```

And then constructed the labels with:

```
Label label1 = new Label(labelStyle);
Label label2 = new Label(labelStyle);
```

Well you are now passing the same reference of the LabelStyle object to each label, instead of passing a copy of the LabelStyle. So when you change the the style of one of the labels you are actually changing the LabelStyle that all labels refer to. One easy solution is to pass a copy of the LAbelStyle to the each label:

```
Label label1 = new Label(new LabelStyle(labelStyle));
```

This is called the copy constructor and it will pass a copy of the LabelStyle instead of the actual reference.

Comment: good one. Just wanted to write the same and noticed your answer.

Comment: I didn't use that constructor, see my edits above. There's a constructor that will use a LabelStyle bitmap font, Color...do I need to create those (BitmapFont) and use the other constructor? Or is there a way to create a LabelStyle and assign it later after using the constructor I already have?

Comment: Well you are passing a skin, internally when you pass a skin the Label(text, skin.get(LabelStyle.class)) is called, so you are still passing the same reference around. Best way to do it is instead of passing the skin pass Label(text, new LabelStyle(skin.get(LabelStyle.class)). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Made all labels that way too. Can I still assign the background as: lblGameMessage.getStyle().background = skinLibgdx.newDrawable ?

Comment: No that will still change the background of the shared style. Weird that it doesnt work, can you post the new code?

Comment: Changed the code above to show new construction. But if I cannot do the getStyle().background, do I use setStyle(Label.LabelStyle style)? I don't see methods though to target the background...

Comment: Ok you are still passing the same reference around. Instead of: lblLevel = new Label("Level: ", skinLibgdx.get(LabelStyle.class)); do:  lblLevel = new Label("Level: ", new LabelStyle(skinLibgdx.get(LabelStyle.class))); You are taking the reference and passing it to the copy constructor of LabelStyle, this should work.

Comment: Ah, right! had to use the 'new' in there! Works great, thanks!